# How to ask for a sabbatical?

Tags: career-development, europe

I'm currently working on a project in a company for over a year. It's a contracting company, so changing a project isn't a big issue. I want to do it, but the thing is that I plan to take a sabbatical first in 4 months, travel around the world for 4 months, and go back.

Nobodyow much time earlier should I ask the company for such a thing? I've never done that yet, is there some general rule? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a company policy, rulebook or employee handbook available? What does it say about extended holidays and absences?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to:

1. Think about why you want to take a sabbatical. If you're taking it because you can't stand your job (say), then a sabbatical doesn't solve that. Also, think hard about your financial situation if you do take a sabbatical
2. Review your staff handbook or intranet on sabbaticals. You may find that there is a set procedure for requesting them. It may be stated that the company doesn't offer sabbaticals
3. Approach your manager in your 121 and informally lay out your plan. Outline how you suggest that your work is covered during the sabbatical and how you plan to hand that work over to a suitable colleague
4. Finally, follow the procedure set out for taking a sabbatical. HR and payroll will need to know your end and start dates in the office

Comment: (+1)  2a.  Find out if your medical/dental plans will cover you during sabbaticals, and if so where you are going.

Comment: Upvoted - but also need to stress *do all this now* - only 4 months notice for this kind of thing is getting to the limit of reasonable notification. For example, I've made sure to give my bosses a good year's warning I was looking to take a 5-week trip to Europe - you don't have to provide exact dates this far out, just "starting about September"